# How to store user authentication info?

Tags: c#, windows, ms-office

In our project we use MS Office add-ins (C#) to connect the webservices (C#) on the company's servers. Today every time when a user wants to send something via the addins they have to login from the addins.
We'd like to store authentication data of the user on their computer once they are logged in. 
How can it be implemented?

Comment: Sounds like it'd be safer to request the authorisation from office/windows rather than storing it yourself!

Comment: I agree. Why not enable Windows authentication on the service side and let windows / Active Directory do the heavy lifting? This has the added value of allowing groups / roles in to the mix, should you need it at a later time.

Comment: Are the users logged into windows using company server credentials?  Or is there a separate identity?  If there is a separate identity, have a look at Windows Credential Manager.  You can view it in a UI using Control Panel\User Accounts and Family Safety\Credential Manager.  If they are already logged on, you could use something like this... Uri uri = new Uri("http://tempuri.org/");
ICredentials credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
NetworkCredential credential = credentials.GetCredential(uri, "Basic");

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using Windows authentication on the web service. Have you verified the host name for the web service URL is in the Intranet zone in Internet Explorer? I don't remember anywhere in Office you need to configure "safe" domains but that would be the second place I would look.